# Why is tailwind CSS not applying psuedo classes such as hover to my HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, tailwind-css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="output.css" CDN FOR SO Purposes-->
</head>

<body class="bg-gray-100">
  <main>
    <div class="flex justify-center items-center min-h-screen">
      <div class="grid-flow-row max-w-[330px] w-full bg-white p-8 rounded-lg shadow-lg">
        <div class="mx-auto">
          <img class="" src="../src/img/logo.gif" alt="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="border w-full"></div>
        <div class="grid justify-items-center content-center">
          <form class="grid justify-items-center content-center">
            <input class="border mt-2 rounded-md p-1" type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="username">
            <input class="border mt-2 rounded-md p-1" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="current-password">
          </form>
          <button class="rounded bg-gray-300 mt-4 text-white font-bold h-8 w-1/2" onclick="">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

On the button when I add hover:bg-gray-400 nothing happens when you hover over it. It keeps the bg-gray-300 class and is not overridden but does not style with the pseudo class as expected. I'm trying to get pseudo classes to work but I just can't seem to figure it out. The issue does not lay in my code. It is in the setup of tailwind and I followed tailwindcss's directions to the t. They had to have changed the commands and not updated the docs

file structure is as follows

```
SRC↓
   |>dist>[index.html, output.css]
   |>node_modules>[lots of stuff]
   |>src>[img>[logo.gif], input.css]
   |>package-lock.json
   |>package.json
   |>tailwind.config.js
```

Below is my config file.

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./dist/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Assuming you mean for the button - adding `hover:bg-gray-400` to the snippet worked just fine. Could you update your question/snippet to include the code you are using for the hover?

Comment: @chazsolo I believe the issue lies in my output.css folder I used CDN key in my project and it worked I don't think the build 'built' properly. my output.css is only a few hundred lines which is a few thousand short of what it should be here is the command I'm using to build it
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch

Comment: If the `hover:bg-gray-400` selector is not in your output.css, then Tailwind never parsed it to add it to the build. You could (1) try adding it to a safelist to verify it works without the CDN, (2) ensure your `input.css` has the Tailwind directives (variants like :hover are placed at the end if you don't specify them specifically), and (3) check for typos or other things that could cause the build not to pick up the class

Comment: @chazsolo Getting Unknown rule for all three tailwind directives base, components, utilities.

Comment: Sounds like your IDE just doesn't recognize it? The build should work, regardless.

Comment: Switched the settings in vscode no longer unknown but I rebuilt everything my output.css only has a few hundred lines in it not even any pseudo classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output file for tailwind can be small because of tree-shaking. The classes that aren't used won't be put in the file when running the build command. I had just not realized that I didn't add --Watch at the end of the command to keep building in the dev environment. So absolutely make sure you add --Watch to the end of
`npx tailwindcss -i 'input file' -o 'output file'.css`